# How to populate drop down values for multiple Google Forms using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdIxr-JJHfo169kQ9RCZVthlmkfCtT7SiQPY5ychh0ZRszfFg/viewform?usp=sf_link) where I ask several people to provide feedback for N people.

The questions in the Google Form will be the same for all feedback providers, but each feedback provider will be asked to provide feedback to different people.

I'd like to have multiple forms that I send out to feedback providers with the same questions but have the first drop-down populated with the list of their respective feedback recipients. Following that, I'd like the responses across all feedback providers to be collated in the same spreadsheet.

I tried the following code. I've built arrays of all feedback receivers for each feedback provider. I was hoping to use that array to populate the drop-down menu. It works, but through each iteration in the for loop, it overwrites the previous iteration. You can find the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/179TI57n-yhSZ1TbBzw5IlHHVYIawyA4_g9uu_7sEIOk/edit?usp=sharing).

```
var ssID = "179TI57n-yhSZ1TbBzw5IlHHVYIawyA4_g9uu_7sEIOk";
var formID = "1HvwvEaf3mCscVmYfrS4Zsn58pqznh8rvg4LCPLMBGMw";

function questionID(){
  var arrQuestions = FormApp.openById(formID).getItems();

  for (let i = 0; i < arrQuestions.length; i++) {
    var questionID = arrQuestions[i].getId().toString();
    Logger.log('entry.' + questionID + '&');
  }
}


function providerList() {
  var ssProviderList = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Map Feedback Providers");
  var arrProviderList = ssProviderList.getRange("A2:H").getValues();

  // loop through each row in spreadsheet
  for (let i = 0; i < arrProviderList.length; i++){

    // create a blank array for each feedback provider to fill with the Avengers they need to provide feedback for
    let arrAvengers = [];

    // loop through each row starting at column C
    for (let j = 2; j < arrProviderList[i].length; j++){

      if ((arrProviderList[i][j] == "") || (arrProviderList[i][j] == null)) {
        break;
      }
      else {
        arrAvengers.push(arrProviderList[i][j]); // place all Avengers listed for each provider inside the blank array
      }
    }

    Logger.log(i + 1 + ') Provider: ' + arrProviderList[i][0] + '\nArray: ' + arrAvengers);
    FormApp.openById(formID).getItemById("217536202").asListItem().setChoiceValues(arrAvengers); // update drop dwon with Avengers

    Logger.log("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1HvwvEaf3mCscVmYfrS4Zsn58pqznh8rvg4LCPLMBGMw/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.217536202=" + arrAvengers + "&entry.192318046&entry.703889307&entry.201973220&entry.468746612&entry.2058453829&entry.1670526684&entry.73658514")
  }
}
```

I tried populating the URL with parameters but that didn't work. I got the below error when accessing this link for Pepper Potts:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1HvwvEaf3mCscVmYfrS4Zsn58pqznh8rvg4LCPLMBGMw/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.217536202=Tony+Stark&entry.192318046&entry.703889307&entry.201973220&entry.468746612&entry.2058453829&entry.1670526684&entry.73658514

[image]I'm not sure where I went wrong nor how to resolve this? Has anyone managed to populate drop-down values with a similar use case to mine?

If Happy Hogan were to receive the feedback form then I'd want his drop-down values to display:
[image]

If Phil Coulson were to receive the feedback form then I'd want Groot's drop-down value to display:
[image]

I've also noticed that the IDs generated from my questionID() function isn't the same as the IDs found in the pre-filled link. Why is that? I thought they would be the same, no?

FYI - I'm unable to Inspect webpages on my Google Form on my company laptop in case someone suggests that!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output values you expect using your sample input values?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I've just edited my post adding more pictures to illustrate what I mean. I hope that helps!

Comment: I've been able to provide different drop-down lists to different users, but that required building (and rebuilding) the original form each time a new person opened it. You should be able to achieve this through apps scripts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.